# Ubuntu clears Alias after closing the terminal's window

Tags: linux, ubuntu, alias, ubuntu-15.04

When I defined some aliases on Ubuntu vivid(15.04) via the terminal, it clears all aliases after I close the window. What can the problem be?

Comment: If you want a permanent alias, you need to put them in `~/.bash_aliases` in form of e.g. `alias install='sudo apt-get install'`.

Comment: There is no bash.aliases on my home directory And I dont know how to add command with starts "if" and finishes"fi" for aliases.

Comment: Just create the file then. 2nd question: bash scripts?

Comment: I tried to create the file and then again I defined some aliases via the terminal but it doesnt work

Comment: Not via the terminal, but write/add them to the file.

Comment: which format I need to use? For there are something looks like this
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

Comment: I added some alias command to this file and after that I restart the terminal but it doesnt work. Even I restart the Laptop but the result is same

Comment: Yeah! Finally I got it. Thanks All of you! I just typed wrongly /.bash.aliases instead of /.bash_aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem. It works as intended.

You set up a temporary alias. You exit the shell. The temporary alias is gone like the evening wind.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating temporary aliases, That's why those are getting removed.

The issue of aliases getting cleared after closing the terminal window on any Linux distros including Ubuntu Vivid (15.04) can be resolved by defining your aliases in the ~/.bashrc file.

To do this, **follow these steps:**

Open the `~/.bashrc` file using a text editor:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Define your aliases in the file using the following syntax:

```
alias alias_name='command'
```

For example:

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

Save the file and exit the text editor.

To apply the changes immediately, source the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Your aliases should now persist across terminal sessions, and you won't lose them when you close the terminal window.

By following this simple step, you'll have your aliases available every time you open a new terminal session.